# Side scroller style scene with gravity

Tags: sprite-kit

I've started learning sprite kit and I think I've got the basics but now I'm struggling with something.

I want to create a game that has a 'Streets of rage' type feel to it whereby the user can move up and down, but isn't jumping, they're still on a 2D plane. But I also want them to be effected by gravity e.g stairs etc. like the following picture.

[image]

Am I right in assuming that I should have my background image with colliders around the blue and brown edges, and then create a physicsbody collider located at the feet of my player/players so that it looks like they can move against the background, but when their feet reach the top it would stop?

Could I then place other obstacles like rocks etc on that path that they would be able to collide into, but that could also sit over the path and the sky? How would I handle the fact that these could be constantly colliding depending on the position?

I appreciate there isn't any code here, but I'm trying to understand the concept around this before I jump in coding a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a categoryBitMask to separate the different planes of objects.
And I would play with collisionBitMask/contactTestBitMask depending from the plane the player is in, in addition to the z-order.

Thus you can have a rock that collides your player if they are both in the same line else the player would walk behind/front.